# How do I call this function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call this function in Javascript but it wont work.

```
eval("function f() { return x + 1;}")
```

I called it by typing `function f(12);`

Comment: `function f(x)`. But what book is this? Learning you to use `eval`.

Comment: Rule 1: Don't use `eval`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The book is called javascript the definitive guide

Comment: It is telling you that it isn't a good idea to use it right?

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST you eval.. you should give `x` to the function as a parameter. So it should be :

```
eval("function f(x) { return x + 1;}")
```

But you could just write it as:

```
function f(x) { 
    return x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[eval() in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)**

The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument.

If the argument is an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If the argument is one or more JavaScript statements, eval() executes the statements.

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = eval("x*y") ;
var b = eval("2+2") ;
var c = eval("x+17")";

var res = a + b + c;
```

**Output:**

```
200
4
27
```

Create your function like this:

```
function f(x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```